# On clicking Button it should Navigate to other page and keeps the same scrolls position. -Javascript , Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, .net, scrollbar

On clicking on Button, it is navigating to other page and over there I need to keep the scroll bar at the previous page position using javascript or jquery

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very extensive. Please provide your code.

I would assume that you do not stop the event propagation.
try this:

```
$( "#element" ).on( "click", function( e ) {
  // do something
  return false;
});
```

Comment: $( "#element" ).on( "click", function( e ) {
window.location.href="/sample/page/";
//once the navigation happened, I need to set the scroll bar at the same place (like previous).
  
});

Comment: Ah, ok i understood you wrong.You can easily set an anker "/sample/page/#anker".
this should work

Comment: I have tried this #anker trick. The drawback is when the page doesn’t render completely due to internet/some other issues and then manually reloading the page I need the scroll to be on top asusual. As the URL contains anker when I relaod, the scroll will not come to the top. And I am stuck here

Comment: just remove the hash after page load. s.t. like this should work
`location.hash = '';`

Comment: How should I do it after page load?

Comment: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   location.hash = '';
}, false);`

on the new page. this should work.